# Cache-control policy for search resource on RESTful API

Tags: rest, cache-control

I'm creating a RESTful API (using MVC.NET) to allow external access to a business system.  The API includes a search resource.  The resource takes the URI form "/example/search/pages/1/?query=something".

Example: To search for pizza you would access the URI "/example/search/pages/1/?query=pizza" which would give you the first 10 results.  To get the second page of results you would request "/example/search/pages/2/?query=something" etc.

I've used the cache-control HTTP header to enable public caching of all the resources on the API with the aim of dramatically reducing the load on the server(s) serving the API web app.

However I'm not sure what caching policy to use for the search resource.  As the resource (and it's URI) vary depending on what you search for, there's seems little point caching the page.  What caching policy (i.e. caching via the cache-control HTTP header) do people recommend for search resources on RESTful APIs?  No caching?  Private caching with a very short expiry time?  Public caching with short expiry?

Answer (score 10):

Most proxy will not cache anything that uses a querystring.

If you want caching, I'd suggest crafting new URIs for your search request using a POST-Redirect-GET pattern.

POST search
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

term=something

303 See Other
Location: /search/something/1

This will enable caching more agressively, but you'll have to craft those URIs and will still get hit by the initial POST. That said, if it's the query that's problematic, this will solve the problem nicely.

Comment: My initial reaction is that using POST in this way isn't very RESTful. That said, if you think of POSTing to the search resource as creating a new search request, and the redirect is to a search request or search handle resource, then I see how this could be made RESTful and resource-oriented. That said, I feel that your answer as written encourages a non-RESTful use of the POST verb.

Comment: uh no it doesn't, it models the post-redirect-get pattern which allows for creating a resource on POST and redirecting to it, for example when using complex queries, which is exactly what you're talking about here. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get for more information. Nothing *anywhere* in the definition of ReST is there any discussion about what POST can or can't do. Don't trust me? See http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post

Comment: You incorrectly assume I haven't read Fielding's dissertation. I have no hangup about the use of POST, nor about the redirect to another resource. For whatever reason, and perhaps it was a lack of thoroughness when I first read your answer, the difference between your proposal and an RPC style API are too subtle. I think it hinges that the resource orientedness is conveyed only by the redirect URI and so the point is easily missed. This is compounded by the fact that PRG predated widespread REST adoption and is most commonly associated with "how to prevent double POSTs"

Comment: PRG documented circa 2003, ReST 2000, HTTP 1.0 (and its provision for not resending non-idempotent methods for refreshes) 96. As for your insistance on finding a relation between creating a search resource and then retrieving it and RPC, I don't see it, please explain yourself more specifically, what remote procedure am i calling here? And since when does any RPC support redirects to named resources, or resource creation for that matter?

Comment: The distinction is too subtle. You either disagree or misunderstand, which I'm okay with since my comments make my case regardless of whether your answer remains as is. PRG was in widespread use at least as early as 1998, typically to avoid double posts.

Answer (score 1):

public caching with an appropriate max-age is what you want for this - the value of max-age will be application specific and is a subjective judgement call you have to make.

You have to balance the risk of serving stale responses against the reward of not having to compute every request.. If this risk is extremely high then shorten the time - but just be conscious that by doing this you are increasing load of your origin server. It's a good idea to monitor usage patterns and server loads in order to establish that your initial judgement is correct.

This wasn't part of your question but if I was you I would move the pagination into the query part of the URI, so

/example/search/pages/1/?query=something

would become:

/example/search?term=something&page=1

It's not essential but it will be more intuitive for developers, and you can hit it easier with an HTML form